# Angular/Bootstrap css alignment issue

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am using bootstrap grid system and angular `ng-repeat` to display flight route information.

It works as expected but in some cases when Outbound flight has more connections than Inbound flight, flight path (blue line) gets interrupted and stays one the same level as second flight in the Outbound. I want in current scenario line to go all the way down and each Inbound/Outbound flight path length be in sync and in respect to each other.

[Plunker code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nS6hnIAYWrv5kIGFf2CW?p=preview)

[image]

HTML:

```
    <div class="roundtrip">
        <div class="col-md-6">Outbound

            <div class="trip" ng-repeat="departureFlight in ticket.route.departureFlights">

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{departureFlight.departureTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{departureFlight.cityFrom}} ({{departureFlight.flyFrom}})</div>
                </div>


                <div class="flight-path">
                    <div class="flight-path">
                        <div class="flight-duration">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime-departureFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{departureFlight.cityTo}} ({{departureFlight.flyTo}})</div>
                </div>

                <div class="connection" ng-if="departureFlight.transferFlight">
                   {{departureFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr wait
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Inbound

            <div class="trip" ng-repeat="returnFlight in ticket.route.returnFlights">

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{returnFlight.departureTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{returnFlight.cityFrom}} ({{returnFlight.flyFrom}})</div>
                </div>


                <div class="flight-path">
                    <div class="flight-path">
                        <div class="flight-duration">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime-returnFlight.departureTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="flight align-bottom">
                    <div class="date-time col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                        <div class="flight-time">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mma"}}</div>
                        <div class="flight-date">{{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"EEE, MMM d, y"}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-2">{{returnFlight.cityTo}} ({{returnFlight.flyTo}})</div>
                </div>

                <div class="connection" ng-if="returnFlight.transferFlight">
                    {{returnFlight.arrivalTime | date:"h:mm"}}hr wait
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.searchResult {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.align-bottom {  /*added*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.roundtrip {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.trip {
  //width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flight {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.date-time {
  text-align: center;
}
.flight-path {
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  min-height: 135px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: #6090FF;
}

.flight-duration {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  left:-15px;
}

.connection {
  height: 40px;
  align-self: center;
  width: 70px;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```